# Launching a file after Installation

Tags: installshield-2010

I have created two releases for my Installshield Basic MSI Project.
I want to launch the executable, on click of the finish button when the Installation completes. I have two different executables. I want to launch first executable when the user has built "Release1" and the other executable if the user had built "Release2".
How can I achieve this?
Is it possible to do it, without using any Installscript custom action?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Look up release flags and the [ISReleaseFlags](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q106453) property. Use it similarly to case C on the linked article, but instead as the condition to the actions which launch your executables.